# Where is glTextureVertexPointer defined?

Tags: opengl, opengl-2.0

I cant finding out where is glTextureVertexPointer defined, there is no such function in my c++ or java opengl games and i've already included and tested everything from opengl.

i am trying to call it this way

```
glTextureVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, texVerts);
```

i really need this function in order to draw certain sprites from my texture spritesheet.
i cant find this function in google,
also, i need to know its full source code if possible.
what is more interesting is that i cant find that function even in the official opengl pages.

i have taken the function from this answer: [OpenGL spritesheets - beginner needs some guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568559/opengl-spritesheets-beginner-needs-some-guidance/1568666#1568666)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function. There is `glTexCoordPointer`, which would seem to have the signature you're looking for.

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568559/opengl-spritesheets-beginner-needs-some-guidance/1568666#1568666

Comment: @БайИван: Looks like a simple mistake to me.